# Install GCC: fatal error: gnu/stubs-32.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I'm using a server with Centos 6.6. I don't have root access and I want to install the gcc-4.8.1 to my own directory. I found a solution and I run the following commands:

```
wget http://www.netgull.com/gcc/releases/gcc-4.8.1/gcc-4.8.1.tar.gz
tar zxvf gcc-4.8.1.tar.gz 
cd gcc-4.8.1
./contrib/download_prerequisites
cd ..
mkdir objdir
cd objdir
$PWD/../gcc-4.8.1/configure --prefix=$HOME/gcc-4.8.1 --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,go
make
```

I got errors when running the `make` command. It reports the following information:

```
configure: error: `CC' has changed since the previous run:
configure:   former value:  `/home/mypath/software/try_gcc2/objdir/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/mypath/software/try_gcc2/objdir/./gcc/ -B/home/mypath/software/try_gcc2/installed/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/home/mypath/software/try_gcc2/installed/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /home/mypath/software/try_gcc2/installed/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include -isystem /home/mypath/software/try_gcc2/installed/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sys-include   '
configure:   current value: `/home/mypath/software/try_gcc2/objdir/./gcc/xgcc -B/home/mypath/software/try_gcc2/objdir/./gcc/ -B/home/mypath/gcc-4.8.1/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/home/mypath/gcc-4.8.1/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /home/mypath/gcc-4.8.1/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include -isystem /home/mypath/gcc-4.8.1/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sys-include   '
configure: error: in `/home/mypath/software/try_gcc2/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libgcc':
configure: error: changes in the environment can compromise the build
configure: error: run `make distclean' and/or `rm ./config.cache' and start over
make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/mypath/software/try_gcc2/objdir'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/mypath/software/try_gcc2/objdir'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I cannot figure what's wrong with my command. Thank you all for helping me!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the solution. When I'm trying to build gcc-5.2.0, it reports that my server does not have 32-bit libraries. It also informs that if I still want to install anyway, I can add `--disable-multilib` when building. I tried and now the build is running normally.